# Intellij Not Booting From Docky - Also Shows Wrong Name

Tags: icons, docky, intellij

Updated Intellij today to 2017.1 but today I noticed that when I hover over my launcher icon in Docky it displays a label of a very old project that I no longer have. I am not sure if it displayed this before, I never really paid much attention to this until now.

Intellij is also unable to be booted up from Docky when I click on it, it works however in the default unity launcher when I click on the icon likeso here:

[Picture of it on normal launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJSwz.png)

It also displays the name of the icon as just Intellij IDEA Community Edition when I hover over it so this probably means that it is a Docky problem rather than Intellij's problem

I have tried to delete the intellij desktop launcher in `/usr/share/applications` and also in `.local/share/applications` but every time I then create a new desktop icon from intellij Tools-->Create Desktop Entry it still shows the same thing.

I have also moved the old intellij configuration because I thought that it might be interfering with the desktop icon name (I moved them in case if I still need them) but that didn't change anything.

Here is the picture (in the link) of the icon on the Docky launcher showing a label of the old version of a project that I don't even have anymore. As you can see it also displays in the text a  2016.3 version of intellij as well but I am already updated to 2017.1 As you can see it also displays in the text a 2016.3 version of intellij as well but I am already updated to 2017.1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting on ubuntuforums someone suggested to just uninstall docky and try again. I tried to do that and it didn't work at first even by calling `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get purge docky` after calling `sudo apt-get remove docky`. I thought that calling those commands would delete configuration files.. which it should but when I installed docky back it would reappear with the same exact configuration of the dock that I had just uninstalled

I then went on nautillus and typed in 'docky' and that's where I was able to find folders of it's configuration files and manually delete them from there.